# Erro de String or binary data would be truncated - SQL

Tags: sql-server

Essa é a estrutura da minha tabela;

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoaldesenv.dbo.Conformidade (
    [ID numeric] numeric(19,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Validacao int NULL,
    Arquivo varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL,
    CodigoAudinUJ varchar(6) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NOT NULL,
    Remessa numeric(19,0) NULL,
    ChaveRegistro varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL,
    NaoConformidade varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL,
    Detalhe varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL,
    Reincidencia int NULL,
    FalsoPositivo numeric(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NULL,
    Resolvida int NULL,
    Observacao varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI NULL,
    DataEntrada date NULL,
    DataFalsoPositivo date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__NaoConfo__ADCA4E927FFBBC86 PRIMARY KEY ([ID numeric])
) GO;
```

Esse é o insert que estou fazendo na tabela;

```
INSERT INTO Pessoaldesenv.dbo.Conformidade
(
Validacao, 
Arquivo, 
CodigoAudinUJ, 
Remessa, 
ChaveRegistro, 
NaoConformidade, 
Detalhe, 
Reincidencia, 
FalsoPositivo, 
Resolvida, 
Observacao, 
DataEntrada, 
DataFalsoPositivo)
VALUES(
1, 
'ARQUIVO1',
'CodigoAudinUJ', 
0, 
'CHAVE_REGISTRO1',  
'NAO CONFORMIDADE1', 
'', 
0, 
0, 
0, 
'', 
'2004-07-12', 
'2004-07-12'
);
```

Estou utilizando SQL serve, porque será que está dando o erro de **String or binary data would be truncated** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre geralmente quando tenta inserir uma `string` maior que o campo aguenta.

Ex: CodigoAudinUJ varchar(6)
Se você inserir uma `string` com 7 caracteres ou mais, dará erro.
No caso, `CodigoAudinUJ`.

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando adicionar um valor maior que a coluna permite.

A sua coluna `CodigoAudinUJ` possui tamanho 6 e você está tentando inserir 13 caracteres.